# Changing path from app.js to a different js file for node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to change my default path from app.js to my other file server.js where all my application logic is. Now, I am really confused as how I should go about it. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. By default when I run my program, it goes to app.js. I want to change it to server.js by default. How can I do that?

```
package.json
{
  "name": "apiplayground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "ejs":"^2.5.7",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.34",
    "pm2": "^2.9.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
}
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error');
    });

    module.exports = app;

bin/www
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../server');
var debug = require('debug')('apiplayground:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

server.js

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(myParser.vjson());// parse application/json
var dbi;



app.get('/home', function (req, res) {
    res.render('pages/home');});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change your starting point, import your app.js file in first line of your server.js, and it should work the same

```
require('./app/app');
```